# PHP explode function find last child

Tags: php, html, plugins

I have a php plugin that explodes one line into several lines.

```
$graph_lines = explode( ";", $content );
$output= '';
$output .= '<ul class="lpd-bullet-list';
if($image){
    $output .= ' lpd-bl-custom-icon';    
}
if($style){
    $output .= ' '.esc_attr($style);    
}
$output .= '">';

foreach ($graph_lines as $line) {
    if($line){

        $output .= '<li>';
        $output .= $image;
        $output .= $line;
        $output .= ';';
        $output .= '</li>';

    }
}

$output .= '</ul>';
echo $output;
```

After each line in the end it set `;` Thats OK, but how to set `.` for last element? Is it possible?

Mey be i need to use `end()` function or another?

Help me please!

Comment: can you post expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of line `sizeof($graph_lines)` and create a counter in your foreach.

Exemple :

```
   $numberofline = sizeof($graph_lines);
    $i=0;
    foreach ($graph_lines as $line) {
        if($line){
            $i++;
            $endofline=";";
            if($i==$numberofline)
            {
                $endofline=".";
            }
            $output .= '<li>';
            $output .= $image;
            $output .= $line;
            $output .= $endofline;
            $output .= '</li>';

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not very sure about your output but yes you can use end function like this:

```
$last_index = end(array_keys($graph_lines));
foreach ($graph_lines as $index => $line) {
    if ($index == $last_index) {
        // last index
    } else {
        // perform other tasks
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use like this:

```
foreach ($graph_lines as $line) {
    if($line){

        $output .= '<li>';
        $output .= $image;
        $output .= $line;
        $output .= ';';
        if (next($graph_lines)==false) $output .= '.';//not sure where you put it.
        $output .= '</li>';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Count the array. and check that with the `$i`.

```
$count = count($graph_lines);
$i = 0;
foreach ($graph_lines as $line) {
    if ($line) {
        if ($i == $count) {
            $output .= '<li>';
            $output .= $image;
            $output .= $line;
            $output .= '.';
            $output .= '</li>';
        } else {
            $output .= '<li>';
            $output .= $image;
            $output .= $line;
            $output .= ';';
            $output .= '</li>';
        }
    }
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: //output   -  what is this?

Comment: `//output` is the what do you want to output at last. Show us what output do you want there

Comment: check now. I forgot to add `$i++`.

Comment: Nope... I get ; after each

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = "a;b;c;d;s;r;t;g";
$content = rtrim($content, ";");
$content = ltrim($content, ";");
$graph_lines = explode(";", $content);
$output = '';
$output .= '<ul class="lpd-bullet-list">';

$last = count($graph_lines) - 1;
$i = 0;
foreach ($graph_lines as $line) {
    if ($line) {
        $output .= '<li>';
        $output .= $line;
        $output .= ($last == $i)? '.' : ";";
        $output .= '</li>';
        $i++;
    }
}

$output .= '</ul>';
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an shorthand IF to check if the current line is matching the last element in the array.

```php
foreach ($graph_lines as $line) {
    if($line){

        $output .= '<li>';
        $output .= $image;
        $output .= $line;
        $output .= ( $line === end ( $graph_lines ) ) ? '.' : ';';
        $output .= '</li>';

    }
}
```

An other way is to set a counter and check if the counter is equal to the count() of $graph_lines.

```php
$counter = 1;
$total_items = count ( $graph_lines );

foreach ( $graph_lines as $line ) {
    // do your stuff.
    $output .= ( $counter === $total_items ) ? '.' : ';';
    $counter++;
}
```